# How to post to event to specific window on MacOS?

Tags: macos, nsevent, cgeventtap

I am trying to post a command + mouse drag event to a specific window.

- Create an NSEvent
- Post the underline cgevent

It does not work whether with `postToPid` or `post`. What I want to achieve is that: there are maybe multiple window at the same position, I just want to drag the window that I care about to a new position.

```swift
let windowNumber = 20 // should be a specific window number
let position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
let newLoc = CGPoint(x: 20, y:20)
let downNSEvent = NSEvent.mouseEvent(
    with: .leftMouseDown,
    location: position,
    modifierFlags: .command,
    timestamp: TimeInterval(),
    windowNumber: Int(windowNumber),
    context: nil, eventNumber: 0, clickCount: 1, pressure: 1.0
)
let downEvent = downNSEvent?.cgEvent
let flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
let eventSource = CGEventSource(event: downEvent)
downEvent?.flags = flags
downEvent?.setIntegerValueField(.mouseEventWindowUnderMousePointer, value: windowNumber)
downEvent?.setIntegerValueField(.mouseEventWindowUnderMousePointerThatCanHandleThisEvent, value: windowNumber)
downEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
//        downEvent?.postToPid(sourcePid!)

usleep(500_000)

// drag event
var newLoc: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y)
if left {
    newLoc.x = destinationBounds.minX - 10
} else {
    print("To right")
    newLoc.x = destinationBounds.maxX + 10
}

print("Move to position: \(newLoc)")

let dragNSEvent = NSEvent.mouseEvent(
    with: .leftMouseDragged,
    location: newLoc,
    modifierFlags: .command,
    timestamp: TimeInterval(),
    windowNumber: Int(windowNumber),
    context: nil, eventNumber: 1, clickCount: 1, pressure: 1.0
)
let dragEvent = dragNSEvent?.cgEvent

dragEvent?.flags = flags
dragEvent?.setIntegerValueField(.mouseEventWindowUnderMousePointer, value: windowNumber)
dragEvent?.setIntegerValueField(.mouseEventWindowUnderMousePointerThatCanHandleThisEvent, value: windowNumber)
dragEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
//        dragEvent?.postToPid(sourcePid!)
guard dragEvent != nil else {return}

usleep(500_000)

let upNSEvent = NSEvent.mouseEvent(
    with: .leftMouseUp,
    location: newLoc,
    modifierFlags: .command,
    timestamp: TimeInterval(),
    windowNumber: Int(windowNumber),
    context: nil, eventNumber: 2, clickCount: 1, pressure: 1.0
)

let upEvent = upNSEvent?.cgEvent

upEvent?.flags = flags
upEvent?.setIntegerValueField(.mouseEventWindowUnderMousePointer, value: windowNumber)
upEvent?.setIntegerValueField(.mouseEventWindowUnderMousePointerThatCanHandleThisEvent, value: windowNumber)
upEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
//        upEvent?.postToPid(sourcePid!)
```

I have searched the web and so, found no available solutions.

- [Swift: forward keystrokes to a different process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560084/swift-forward-keystrokes-to-a-different-process)
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent/1454804-posttopid

Comment: How about activating the window first? Do you want to move a window or is a drag event required?

Comment: Actually it is an icon on the menubar. I want to use command + drag to move it around. I try to activate it first, for it seems not working.

Comment: Is a status item? Do you have multiple icons at the same position?

Comment: What I want to do is that: When we open an app, it will have its menu. It may hide certain status item icon. I want to trigger some mouse event to drag target item to other places to make it visible.

Comment: I can use `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` to get all window info(its rect, place etc). But if they are under the menu of others, mouse event cannot be triggered on the status item.

Comment: Is the window onscreen? I don't think you can send an event to a window.

Comment: Yes. The key point. The window is not on screen. Do you have any idea how to handle those windows that are not on screen? The kCGWindowIsOnscreen value is nil.

And after lots of trials, postToPid can be used only with keyboard events; post can be used with keyboard and mouse events.